# Ansible can only provision first machine in multi machine Vagrantfile

Tags: configuration, vagrant, ansible, vagrantfile

I have simple Vagrantfile with 3 machines and Ansible as server provisioner. Vagrantfile looks like this:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

# Jira machine
config.vm.define 'jira' do |jira|
  jira.vm.box = 'puppetlabs/ubuntu-14.04-64-nocm'
  jira.vm.network "private_network", ip:"192.168.77.11"
  jira.vm.hostname = 'jira'
  jira.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.name = 'jira'
  end
end

# Master machine with proxy beetwen mattermost and jira
config.vm.define 'master' do |master|
  master.vm.box = 'puppetlabs/ubuntu-14.04-64-nocm'
  master.vm.network "private_network", ip:"192.168.77.10"
  master.vm.hostname = 'master'
  master.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.name = 'master'
  end
end

# Mattermost machine
config.vm.define 'mattermost' do |mattermost|
  mattermost.vm.box = 'puppetlabs/ubuntu-14.04-64-nocm'
  mattermost.vm.network "private_network", ip:"192.168.77.12"
  mattermost.vm.hostname = 'mattermost'
  mattermost.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.name = 'mattermost'
  end
end

# Provision part
config.vm.provision :ansible do |ansible|
  ansible.limit = 'all'
  ansible.playbook = 'provisioning/main.yml'
  ansible.inventory_path = 'developer'
  ansible.sudo = true
  ansible.verbose = '-vvvv'
end
```

end

After vagrant up, first machine on the list is provisioned correctly but later Ansible cannot ssh to next one. As I saw in debug it still uses the same private key to authenticate to rest of machines. Here is the gist with output from provision: https://gist.github.com/Cosaquee/224a84f171aa8cd458d9ce56e8c8e111.

I just started playing with Ansible so i do not know how to force ansible to use private keys every machine not just one. Maybe the problem is with something else.

Any help would be nice. Thank you.

Comment: can you run the ansible provisioning in each machine block? I know this is duplicate code so not too good but to see if it works - if it works this way, you might need to create a ticket against vagrant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what your config should look like. Notice how the provisioner is nested

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

    # Webserver, jobserver and message queue VM
    config.vm.define "app", primary: true do |app|

        app.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
        app.vm.hostname = "app.restream.vm"
        app.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
        app.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www/app"
        app.vm.synced_folder "../infra", "/var/www/infra"
        app.vm.synced_folder "../widgetcodebucket", "/var/www/widgetcodebucket"
        app.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.10.10.90"

        app.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
            vb.gui = false
            vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--nictype1", "virtio"]
            vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "4096"]
            vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", "4"]
        end

        app.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
            ansible.host_key_checking = false
            ansible.limit = 'all'
            #ansible.verbose = 'vvvv'
            ansible.inventory_path = '../infra/hosts-dev'
            ansible.playbook = "../infra/vm.yml"
            ansible.extra_vars = {
                symfony_env: 'dev',
                ansible_ssh_user: 'vagrant',
                nginx_user: 'vagrant',
                redis_ip: '127.0.0.1',
                redis_port: 6379,
                git_branch: "develop"
            }
        end
    end

    # Statistics and monitoring VM
    config.vm.define "stats" do |stats|
        stats.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
        stats.vm.hostname = "stats.restream.vm"
        stats.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
        stats.vm.synced_folder "../infra", "/var/www/infra"
        stats.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.10.11.11"

        stats.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
            vb.gui = false
            vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--nictype1", "virtio"]
            vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "4096"]
            vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", "4"]
        end

        stats.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
            ansible.limit = 'all'
            ansible.host_key_checking = false
            #ansible.verbose = 'vvvv'
            ansible.inventory_path = '../infra/hosts-dev'
            ansible.playbook = "../infra/stats.yml"
            ansible.extra_vars = {
                symfony_env: 'dev',
                ansible_ssh_user: 'vagrant',
                graphite_db_name: 'graphite',
                graphite_db_engine: 'django.db.backends.mysql',
                graphite_db_user: 'root',
                graphite_db_pass: 'root',
                graphite_db_host: '127.0.0.1',
                graphite_db_port: 3306
            }
        end
    end

end
```